# model.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to learn node.js with mongoose. Simply want to read from database and display result in a browser. I have index.js where I compiled model from schema as

```
var mlink = mongoose.model('mlink',mlinkSchema)
```

Then I exported it so as to use it in server.js file as

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('mlink',mlinkschema);
```

Under server.js, I require it as

```
const mlink = require(__dirname, "../Scripts/index.js");
```

And now, I am using express router as below

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use("/", router);
router.route("/Scripts").get(function(req,res){
  mlink.find({},function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Here I keep on getting error as mlink.find is not a function. Please help I am stuck.

Comment: ok. I was not knowing that people here are helping only if they get a bounty. Thanks for giving me insight. Let admin also authenticate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model('mlink',mlinkschema);
```

It should be

```js
module.exports = mlink;
```

Comment: Sorry, got access now only.. I did change as suggested by you. But the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have a correct model than

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('mlink',mlinkSchema);
```

should work (you had a typo in `mlinkSchema` it needs to have a capital S)

You would import a model like this:

```
const mlink = mongoose.model("mlink");
```

Getting data from MongoDB is time consuming it should be an asynchronous function

```
router.route("/Scripts").get(async function(req,res){
  await mlink.find({},function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at my issue. I did try as you have given. I tried understanding async function and await. But my problem persists. I still get error, with addition as

Comment: can you share your model file? And maybe other code that is related to the operation?

Comment: yes. the code is as below yes..     index.js const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var MSRLinkSchema = new Schema({
    BrCode: { type: Number, min: 5, max: 5, required: true },
  IPAddress: String, BrNameL: String}); var MLink = mongoose.model('MLink', MSRLinkSchema );module.exports = MLink; server.js as below const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Mlink = require(__dirname, "../Scripts/index.js");const router = express.Router(); next part in next comment

Comment: why it is not allowing me to post my code? the next part is app.get("/", function(request,response){
  console.log(__dirname);  response.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, './Scripts')});

});router.route("/Scripts").get(async function(req,res){await MLink.find({},function(err, result){if (err) {res.send(err);}else {res.send(result);}});});app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("server started on port 3000");});module.exports = router; This is almost entire code. please help

Comment: Did you try to follow my answer? Please use `const mlink = mongoose.model("Mlink");` instead of this:  `const Mlink = require(__dirname, "../Scripts/index.js");`

Comment: I did put the line. But I am getting "MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "mlink"." Thank you for your help. It is really complicated. Please help me further.